# Automatically delete data from database table after execution of SQL statements

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

I have a reviewfile.php whereby it reads in a file and process it by the following criteria by inserting the data into database:

1. Duplicated results
2. Results without comments
3. Results of data with source or destination that is "Any".

I have SQL statement for each condition.

After printing results of the SQL statements, i would like delete all data of the database table so that if i upload a new file, insertion of data is fresh.

P.S: I do not want to drop table.

May i seek some help please:)

Below is my codes

```
if(isset($_POST['reviewFile'])){
    if (isset($_POST['fileSelected'])){

        $SelFile = $_POST['fileSelected'];


        $query=$con->prepare("SELECT * from file where file_name = '$SelFile'");
        $query->bind_result($file_id, $uid, $file_name, $file_size);
        $query->execute();
        $query->fetch();
        $query->close();

        $path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/fwrule/fw/fileuploads/';
        $file_to_get = $path.$SelFile;

        $_SESSION['tmpfname'] = $file_to_get;
        $_SESSION['excelReader'] = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($_SESSION['tmpfname']);
        $_SESSION['excelObj'] = $_SESSION['excelReader']->load($_SESSION['tmpfname']);

        $_SESSION['worksheet'] = $_SESSION['excelObj']->getSheet(0);
        $_SESSION['lastRow'] =  $_SESSION['worksheet']->getHighestRow();
        $_SESSION['highestColumn'] = $_SESSION['worksheet']->getHighestColumn();

        //loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
        for ($_SESSION['row'] = 3; $_SESSION['row'] <= $_SESSION['lastRow']; ++$_SESSION['row']) {

            //read a row of data into an array
            $rowData = $_SESSION['worksheet']->rangeToArray('A'.$_SESSION['row']. ':'.$_SESSION['highestColumn'] . $_SESSION['lastRow'], NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

            //insert rows into database
            $InsertData = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO file_data(id, file_id, no, name, source, destination, hit_counts, service, action, track, install_on, time, comment)
            VALUES('', '$file_id', '".$rowData[0][0]."', '".$rowData[0][1]."', '".$rowData[0][2]."', '".$rowData[0][3]."', '".$rowData[0][4]."', '".$rowData[0][5]."', '".$rowData[0][6]."', '".$rowData[0][7]."', '".$rowData[0][8]."', '".$rowData[0][9]."', '".$rowData[0][10]."')");


                $InsertData->execute();
                $InsertData->store_result();


            /*if (!$InsertData = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO file_data(id, file_id, no, name, source, destination, hit_counts, service, action, track, install_on, time, comment)
                    VALUES('', '$file_id', '".$rowData[0][0]."', '".$rowData[0][1]."', '".$rowData[0][2]."', '".$rowData[0][3]."', '".$rowData[0][4]."', '".$rowData[0][5]."', '".$rowData[0][6]."', '".$rowData[0][7]."', '".$rowData[0][8]."', '".$rowData[0][9]."', '".$rowData[0][10]."')"))
            {
                ?>
                <html>
                    <script>
                        window.alert("Error message:: %s\n", $con->error");
                    </script>
                </html>
                <?php
            }*/
        }


        if ($DuplicatedRows = $con->prepare("SELECT id
                      from file_data a
                      join ( SELECT source, destination, hit_counts, service
                               from file_data
                              group by source, destination, hit_counts, service
                             having count(*) > 1 ) b
                        on a.source = b.source
                       and a.destination = b.destination
                        and a.hit_counts = b.hit_counts
                        and a.service = b.service")){

                            $DuplicatedRows->bind_result($id);
                            $DuplicatedRows->execute();
                            $DuplicatedRows->store_result();

                            while($DuplicatedRows->fetch()){

                                $rowNumforDuplicates = ($id+2);
                                $info1 = "Duplicated Rules";

                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>".$rowNumforDuplicates."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$info1."</td>";
                                //echo "<td>".$source."".$destination."".$hit_counts."".$service."</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";

                            }

                            $DuplicatedRows->free_result();
                            $DuplicatedRows->close();

                }
                else{

                    ?>
                    <html>
                        <script>
                            window.alert("Error message:: %s\n", $con->error");
                        </script>
                    </html>
                    <?php
                }

                if ($checkforAny = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM file_data WHERE source collate latin1_swedish_ci = 'any' or destination collate latin1_swedish_ci ='any' "))
                {

                    $checkforAny->bind_result($id);
                    $checkforAny->execute();
                    $checkforAny->store_result();

                    while($checkforAny->fetch()){

                        //row number in excel as the file is reviewed from line 3 onwards, hence 2 is added to the ID value
                        $rowNumforAny = ($id+2);

                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "The one with Any: $rowNumforAny";
                    }

                    $checkforAny->free_result();
                    $checkforAny->close();

                }
                else{

                    ?>
                    <html>
                        <script>
                            window.alert("Error message:: %s\n", $con->error");
                        </script>
                    </html>
                    <?php
                }

                if ($checkforComments = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM file_data WHERE comment = '' "))
                {
                    $checkforComments->bind_result($id);
                    $checkforComments->execute();
                    $checkforComments->store_result();

                    while($checkforComments->fetch()){

                        $rowNumforComments = ($id+2);

                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "The one with with no comments:$rowNumforComments";

                    }
                    echo "</table>";

                    $checkforComments->free_result();
                    $checkforComments->close();
                }
                else {

                    ?>
                    <html>
                        <script>
                            window.alert("Error message:: %s\n", $con->error");
                        </script>
                    </html>
                    <?php
                }

                if ($checkforHitcounts = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM file_data ORDER BY hit_counts ASC|DESC")){

                                $checkforHitcounts->bind_result($id, $hit_counts);
                                $checkforHitcounts->execute();
                                $checkforHitcounts->store_result();

                                while($checkforHitcounts->fetch()){

                                    echo "<br>";
                                    echo "hitcounts:$id";

                                }
                                echo "</table>";

                                $checkforHitcounts->free_result();
                                $checkforHitcounts->close();

                }
                else{

                    ?>
                    <html>
                        <script>
                            window.alert("Error message:: %s\n", $con->error");
                        </script>
                    </html>
                    <?php
                }


                if ($DuplicatedRows == true && $checkforAny == true && $checkforComments == true)
                {
                    $delAllData = $con->prepare("DELETE * from file_data");

                    $delAllData->bind_result();
                    if ($delAllData->execute())
                    {
                        $delAllData->fetch();
                        echo "hi"; 
                    }
                    $delAllData->close();
                }
    }
}
```

The codes are working fine except for the part where I want to delete data from database table.

This is the part that is not working:

```
if ($DuplicatedRows == true && $checkforAny == true && $checkforComments == true)
                {
                    $delAllData = $con->prepare("DELETE * from file_data");

                    $delAllData->bind_result();
                    if ($delAllData->execute())
                    {
                        $delAllData->fetch();
                        echo "hi"; 
                    }
                    $delAllData->close();
                }
```

Comment: because `DELETE *` is invalid and I'll find the duplicate for this; give me a minute. Edit: found and closed.

Comment: Try `TRUNCATE file_data` instead of DELETE FROM. It's faster, and clears the indexes.

Comment: Hi, thanks, it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you run to delete the content is wrong.

The query should be `DELETE FROM file_data`